# Periodic delta potentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, crystals

I want to study a periodic potential made up of delta functions spaced by L. To do that, I wanted to write the symmetry of the system and the conservation laws or degeneracy that happens.

I started with a periodic potential $V(x)=V(x+L)$ which extends over all x. The wave function should have the same symmetry as the potential, so I take a translation operator T and say $T(L)V(x)=V(x)=V(x+L)=V(x)T(L)$ So, V and T(L) commute, $[V,T(L)]=0$.

Translation operators T(x) for any x commute with each other, so T(L) should commute with successive small translations, which eventually make the momentum operator. So $[T(L),p]=0$. So $[T(L),p^2]=0$. Kinetic energy is $E_k$, so $[T(L),E_k]=0$.

Then commutator identities give $[T(L),H]=0$. So $T(L)\psi_n=H\psi_n=E_n\psi_n$.

Because the energy eigenfunctions are also eigenfunctions of translation, I can set boundary conditions $\psi_n(x)=\psi_n(x+L)$ and $\psi_n'(x)=\psi_n'(x+L)$. Then, by convenience, I will consider x between 0 and L and solve the SE as a standard 2 order diff eq: $$\frac{p^2}{2m}\psi_n(x)+\delta(x)\psi_n(x)=E_n\psi(x)$$

My question is this: I do not think I will get an answer like $\psi=exp(-iax/L)u(x)$, which Bloch theorem says I should get. Why is that the case? Is the Bloch theorem meant only for e.g. bound states in solids? I think that might be the problem because here i did not specify if I wanted bound or scattering states.

Comment: Whatever your potential is, it must be acting on the state $\psi_n(x)$ in your last equation. Have you tried to do this for a single delta, then two etc.,?

Comment: @josephh uh oh, the last equation has a mistake. I will fix it. I have done both single and double delta, but I dont think the delta is my confusion here. It looks like any potential with L periodicity will give the same problem.

Comment: Well Bloch's theorem holds for any periodic potential, so forgetting the delta function as you say, the solution would look like $$\Psi(x) =u(x) e^{ikx}$$ You say you think you will not get this answer, but why exactly?

Comment: The final expression of $\psi$ should also have a series of step functions (which comes from delta functions) depending on the number of periodic motions covered in given time

Comment: @josephh my answer will look arbitrary if you take arbitrary V (instead of delta functions). So I could divide my psi by $exp(ikx)$ to get that form but that will be silly and i thought bloch theorem will be deeper.

Answer (score 3):

There is a conceptual mistake at the beginning of your calculations. Periodicity of the potential does not require periodicity of the wavefunctions. Actually, Bloch's theorem doesn't say that. It says that the effect of a transition by $L$ is to leave the same wavefunction **within a phase factor $e^{i k L} $**. It is a mathematical consequence of the theorem, but it is also understandable on the basis that we expect periodicity of the observable density probability $|\psi|^2$, not just $\psi$.

Therefore, your boundary conditions should take into account such more general boundary conditions. That is the same as saying that the translation eigenvectors are not $1$ but $e^{i k L} $. The possible values of $k$ can be easily obtained by requiring a *global* periodicity of the wavefunctions, over the whole periodic boundary condition crystal, i.e. $e^{i k N L}=1 $.
Everything else is independent of the choice of a sum of delta functions instead of continuous potentials.

Answer (score 3):

1. You stated the following equation:
   $$T(L)\psi_n=H\psi_n=E_n\psi_n.$$
   This is not correct. The translation operator and Hamiltonian share an eigenbasis. But the eigenvalue corresponding to $T(L)$ is not $E_n$.
2. The translation operator is unitary. This means that
   $$(T(L))^\dagger=(T(L))^{-1}.$$
   This is easily proved by considering the following form of $T(L)$:
   $$T(L)=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}L\hat{p}/\hbar}.$$
   Thus, we have a notable restriction on the eigenvalues thereof: they satisfy $|\lambda|^2=1$ for $T|\psi\rangle=\lambda|\psi\rangle.$ Proof:
   $$\begin{aligned}\langle\psi|T^\dagger T|\psi\rangle&=\langle\psi|(T^\dagger T)|\psi\rangle\\&=\langle\psi|\psi\rangle\quad\text{or}\\&=(\langle\psi|T^\dagger)(T|\psi\rangle)\\&=|\lambda|^2|\psi\rangle\\\Rightarrow|\lambda|^2&=1\end{aligned}$$
   We thus define the action of the translation operator $T(L)$ as follows:
   $$T(L)\psi=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha}\psi.$$
   The action of this translation operator upon a wave function of the form prescribed by Bloch's theorem is a correct translation of the wave function by $L$. Specifically, with a wave function $$\psi=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha x/L}u(x);\quad u(x)=u(x+L),$$ we have
   $$T(L)\psi=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha(x+L)/L}u(x+L).$$
3. Clearly, the following equations in the question are also incorrect:
   $$\psi(x)=\psi(x+L);\quad \psi'(x)=\psi'(x+L).$$
   There should be an additional phase factor.
4. Bloch's theorem is not "exclusively for bound states." The solutions it predicts are non-normalizable and are used as a basis for wave packets.